# How to zoom image using php

Tags: php, image, image-conversion

There is any possibility to zoom an image in php?
I've searched on google but nothing util found.

If someone has any tips please give it to me. Thank you

Comment: What for? Is it for viewing? Because if so you could use javascript on the client side. If you wanna replace the image with a zoomed one, you can do in PHP using [**`imagecopyresampled`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

Comment: For viewing I want. Thank you

Comment: Are you passing an image using javscript (to php?)

Answer (score 2):

Imagecopyresampled solution here:

```
$zoom=120; //to zoom 120%
$width = imagesx($myimage);
$height = imagesy($myimage);

$new_width = $width * $zoom / 100;
$new_height = $height * $zoom / 100;

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $myimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) php example (and make it large instead of smaller - (smaller is demonstrated in the php.net example), and if you are PASSING a js variable, then you would get something like the following php:

```
<?php
// The file
$imgin = $_POST["dogimg"];  
      //e.g if your img is called dogimg!
$percent = 1.4; //140%

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgin);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_out = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgin);
imagecopyresampled($image_out, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_out, null, 100);
?>
```

However, I should point out that you should be careful when working with file types such as images and I would advise that you put in some [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) to [check that the file is an image](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) at the start (preferably when you upload the image to begin with, if you are uploading the images via a website).

If you're working with pre-uploaded images that you have uploaded on the server, then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

use [imagemagic](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)

```
$geometry = '142x106';
$resize_geo = $geometry.'^';
$crop_geo = $geometry.'+0+0';
`convert $pic_original_path -resize $resize_geo -gravity Center -crop $crop_geo $pic_resized_path`;
```